# Duplicates Records in Loop

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a loop that I am trying to use to echo email addresses based on whether a profile pic is not in a directory /pics. How can I remove duplicates so it only lists the Email once?

```
<?php 

while ($row_Recordset9 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset9)) {
    $ID = $row_Recordset9['ID'];
    $image = '../pics/' . $ID . '.jpg';  
    if (!file_exists($image)) {
        echo $row_Recordset9['Email'].', ';         
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Instead of echoing the email, push it onto an array. Use `array_unique()` to remove duplicates from the array, then echo them.

Comment: @mistermartin But the query can't tell if the file exists.

Comment: Barmer-I have tried in an array without success. Martin-I initially tried DISTINCT but because I am emailing their manager, each ID belongs to an employee and will show up on each row. Any help with setting up the array would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the emails in an array, then use `array_unique()` to remove duplicates.

```
$emails = array();
while ($row_Recordset9 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset9)) {
    $ID = $row_Recordset9['ID'];
    $image = '../pics/' . $ID . '.jpg';  
    if (!file_exists($image)) {
        $emails[] = $row_Recordset9['Email'];       
    }
}
$addresses = implode(',', array_unique($emails));
echo $addresses;
```

Comment: Barmar-Your solution also worked. I appreciate the solution. I initially tried using array_unique without success. This works perfectly.

Comment: Let me guess, you forgot to assign the result of `array_unique` back to the variable. It doesn't modify the array it's given, so you need to use the result.

Comment: Yep. I would end up echoing blank. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You could store results into a temporary array and check against that:

```
$temp = array();
while ($row_Recordset9 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset9)) {
    $ID = $row_Recordset9['ID'];
    $image = '../pics/' . $ID . '.jpg';
    $email = $row_Recordset9['Email'];
    if (!file_exists($image) && !in_array($email, $temp)) {
        $temp[] = $email;
        echo $email.', ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Mister Martin-Your solution worked like a charm. Many thanks.